# Notification if new Audiostream gets opened on Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, audio

I've been through the docs, but I didn't find an answer: If Sndvol is open under Windows 7, it displays new applications that play audio immediately. Now, I didn't find a Notification-Interface in the Core Audio API for that.

How is SndVol doing that? Polling the Stream Enumerator all the time?

Comment: Check the events in event viewer, if you see new events added when a new audio stream is opened, then you might be able to subscribe to those windows events.

Comment: Uh - which "event viewer" do you mean?

Comment: just click start and type event viewer. it should be in the search results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it myself. This type of notification is in the *IAudioSessionManager2* interface, where you can pass a pointer to the *RegisterNotificationSession* method, pointing to the *IAudioSessionNotification* interface. Details can be found here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370969(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370969%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I knew there was something like this... :)